# output NaN value when using apply function to a dataframe with index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use apply function to create 2 new columns. when dataframe has index, it doesn't wokr, the new columns have values of NaN.  If dataframe has no index, then it works. Could you please help? Thanks

```
def calc_test(row):

    a=row['col1']+row['col2']
    b=row['col1']/row['col2']
    return (a,b)

df_test_dict={'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':[10,20,30,40,50]}
df_test=pd.DataFrame(df_test_dict)
df_test.index=['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1']
df_test

    col1    col2
a1  1   10
b1  2   20
c1  3   30
d1  4   40
e1  5   50
```

Now I use apply function, the new creately columns have values of NaN. Thanks for your help.

```
df_test[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1).tolist())
df_test


col1    col2    a   b
a1  1   10  NaN NaN
b1  2   20  NaN NaN
c1  3   30  NaN NaN
d1  4   40  NaN NaN
e1  5   50  NaN Na
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `apply`, you may use the `result_type ='expand'` argument to expand the output of your function as columns of a pandas Dataframe:

```
df_test[['a','b']]=df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1, result_type ='expand')
```

This returns:

```
    col1    col2    a   b
a1  1   10  11.0    0.1
b1  2   20  22.0    0.1
c1  3   30  33.0    0.1
d1  4   40  44.0    0.1
e1  5   50  55.0    0.1
```

Comment: wow, that is a good trick! it works very well. Thanks Sheldon! I appreicate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the return of the `apply` as a DataFrame which has a default indexing of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` which don't exist in your original DataFrame's index. You can see this by looking at the output of `pd.DataFrame(df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1).tolist())`.

Simply remove the `pd.DataFrame()` to fix this problem.

`df_test[['a', 'b']] = df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1).tolist()`